# Ionic footer moves up when i write on mobile

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a simple application consists of a textbox and a footer, the problem i faced that when i write in the textbox  , the footer moves up like this

[image]

What i want is to make the footer fixed at the bottom , and the keyboard appears above the footer .

Here's the code

```html
 <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
  
      <ion-content>

          <input type="text" />

      </ion-content>


        <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">
            <div class="title">Footer</div>
        </div>
      

      
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not implementing  it right

use ion-footer-bar directive

```html
    <ion-content class="has-footer">
      Some content!
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-assertive">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button">Left Button</button>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
      <div class="buttons" ng-click="doSomething()">
        <button class="button">Right Button</button>
      </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionFooterBar/

Comment: I used exactly  your code , and still having the same problem

Comment: I believe you have an issue with ionic-keyboard 

try this 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/keyboardAttach/

Comment: I tried it , and still the same problem , but ionic has mentioned  that  , if you are using Cordova there is no reason not to use the plugin. 

this problem took from me 3 days :/

Comment: then try with andriod manifest file in your build android folder .
you can set up the keyboard options from there

Comment: Yes that was the problem , its  keyboard options  issue . thank you :)

Comment: you are welcome , can you mark my answer as correct :)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

After 3 days i found the solution , 
YourProject\platforms\android\AndroidManifest

Set the android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan